# Java Hibernate. Buscar por la llave

Tags: java, hibernate

Saludos a toda la comunidad. Tengo un problema para realizar una búsqueda en un tabla. La llave de esta tabla son dos campos y estoy realizando la búsqueda con hibernate: El modelo son tres tablas. REGION, CIUDAD, COMUNA. Para la tabla CIUDAD la llave se compone de dos campos: codigoregion y codigociudad. Sin embargo para la búsqueda tengo un lío: sesión.get(Ciudad.class, pcodigociudad).
Pregunta: ¿Cómo asocio el pcodigoregion?. No puedo usar anotaciones, tampoco puedo usar sesión.createquery. Necesito que sea con sesión.get(
Se agradecerá mucho vuestra ayuda.
Larry

Answer (score 0):

Se trata de una tabla con clave primaria compuesta. Por tanto, debe tener ambas claves como atributos, e ir encabezados por la anotación @Id.

Por ejemplo:

```
@Id
private Integer codigoregion;

@Id
private Integer codigociudad;
```

Además, como ambas son clave, debes añadir un constructor que reciba ambos parámetros.

```
public Ciudad(Integer region, Integer ciudad) {
         codigoregion = region;
         codigociudad = ciudad;
}
```

Y con esto, ya deberías poder realizar búsquedas con Hibernate. En el parámetro donde pasas la clave que buscas, debes pasar un objeto Ciudad con las claves que buscas.

```
Ciudad pcodigociudad = new Ciudad(1, 2);
sesion.get(Ciudad.class, pcodigociudad);
```

(Devolvería la ciudad que tenga codigoregion 1 y codigociudad 2)